# Replacing Null value with existing value

Tags: oracle, null, replace

How would it be possible to replace the null value from Order - column with the above existing value that has the the same Document-number?

```
Document    Value   Value2  Order
1234567       4        7    45678
1234567       2        0    Null
```

Comment: In general - impossible because of potential ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which row represents the "above" or "previous" row, you could use `LAG` analytic function along with `NVL`. Something like this:

```
SQL> with test (document, value, value2, corder) as
  2    (select 1234567, 4, 7, 45678 from dual union all
  3     select 1234567, 2, 0, null  from dual
  4    )
  5  select document, value, value2,
  6    -- LAG ... - previous value per document, sorted by VALUE column in descending order
  7    -- If CORDER is null, take its previous value. How? Using NVL
  8    nvl(corder, lag(corder) over (partition by document order by value desc)) corder
  9  from test
 10  order by document, value desc;

  DOCUMENT      VALUE     VALUE2     CORDER
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   1234567          4          7      45678
   1234567          2          0      45678

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for you effort that seems to work. I did actually found solution to my problem by using this:

coalesce(order, MAX(order) OVER (partition by document) .